# Can a polytopal graph be "centrally symmetric" in more than one way?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, symmetry

Let $P,Q$ be two centrally symmetric *convex* polytopes, potentially of different dimensions and combinatorial type, but with the same edge-graph $G$.
The central symmetry of $P$ induces an involutory automorphism $\iota_P\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ of the edge-graph, and likewise $\iota_Q\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ for $Q$.

> **Question:** do we have $\iota_P=\iota_Q$?

---

It was pointed out by David E Speyer in the comments that this question can be interpreted in two different (yet still very related) ways. I admit, I don't know which version is the "right one" to ask for my application, and a solution to either would be welcome.
I suspect that one of the versions is stronger, and this would then be the favorable one. But I also suspect that they are equivalent, in the sense that the answer is *No* to both.

Comment: This is not true even when P=Q. A polytope can have two different involutions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, but to say that $P$ is centrally symmetric means that the linear map $x \mapsto -x$ in the Euclidean space it lives in is maps $P$ to itself, and this map (restricted to $P$) is then called the central symmetry. So I don't understand in what sense a polytope could have two different central symmetries. Maybe you are saying an isometric copy of $P$ has a different one (though that seems hard to imagine...)?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I am not sure I understand. I only care about the central symmetry $x\mapsto -x$ of the polytope, not every involutory symmetry.

Comment: It seems to me that writing $i_Q = i_P$ is confusing, as these are involutions on two different sets. What one wants to write is $i_Q = \sigma \circ i_P \circ \sigma^{-1}$, where $\sigma$ is a bijection from the vertices of $P$ to those of $Q$. Once you note this issue, there are two versions of the question:

Comment: (1) "Given centrally symmetric polytopes $P$ and $Q$ and a bijection $\sigma : v(P) \to v(Q)$ inducing an isomorphism of edge graphs, do we have $i_Q = \sigma \circ i_P \circ \sigma^{-1}$?" (2) "Given centrally symmetric polytopes $P$ and $Q$ with isomorphic edge graphs, does there exist a isomorphism $\sigma$ of the edge graphs with $i_Q = \sigma \circ i_P \circ \sigma^{-1}$?"

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I could have been more formal, but when I say that $P$ and $Q$ have the same edge-graph $G$, I already consider $G$ as an abstract graph and I assume implicit isomorphisms between it and the skeleta of the polytopes. So the involutions live in the same group. I expected that the induced involution commute with all automorphisms anyway and so I don't have to be too precise here. But this might presuppose the answer. Unfortunately I don't quite see how the questions (1) and (2) are different, or at least not obviously equivalent. Can you answer one of them but not the other?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Okay, I start to understand. Until I come up with a more precise version of the question let me say: both (1) and (2) seem nontrivial and interesting to me.

Comment: I started to write this when I thought I had a counterexample to (1): I thought I had made a centrally symmetric polytope whose edge graph was $K_{2n} \setminus C_{2n}$, with negation pairing off one of the two matchings of the $C_{2n}$. But my construction is broken.

Comment: Indeed, I have since learned of a theorem of Grunbaum: A centrally symmetric polytope with $2n$ vertices in $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ can have at most $(1-2^{-d}) \tfrac{(2n)^2}{2}$ edges. So the graph $K_{2n} \setminus C_{2n}$ can't be achieved in any fixed dimension. See Prop 2.1 for a quick proof https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611893 .